# Jmeter Scripts Execution on VSTS

Tags: performance, jmeter

Currently, I'm working with jmeter scripts on Vsts.
I m getting results as aggregate report which consists based on samples.
Any body suggest is there any option to get Transaction based report in vsts.

Answer (score 1):

you have to `explicitly define transaction` using [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) in your scripts, then Aggregate Report displays/saves both sampler level and transaction level results.

Comment: I have executed jmeter script using transaction controller in jmeter and I'm getting expected transaction level results. But when i executed the same scripts on Azure VSTS i'm getting sample based results but not transaction based results. Could you please suggest on this.

Comment: you can try by enabling the check box "Generate Parent Sample". I don't have knowledge in VSTS as of now.